# Why do AWS credentials seem to go missing when creating a kinesis client from a session with the Go SDK?

Tags: go, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to list Kinesis streams

```
session, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    Config: aws.Config{Region: aws.String("sa-east-1"),
        CredentialsChainVerboseErrors: aws.Bool(true)},
    Profile: profile,
})
client := kinesis.New(session)
streams, err := client.ListStreams(client.ListStreamsInput{})
```

The profile is correct and the region is correct but streams is always an empty list, despite there being one stream existing with those parameters. Can you advise why I don't see the stream?

I'm using the Delve debugger with vscode and can see this, where creds has nothing in AccessKeyId etc.

[image]

I've made sure that the credentials are being pointed to with the full path and they contain the required access key and secret.

From the docs

> By default NewSession will only load credentials from the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials).

I also tried

```
session, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    // Specify profile to load for the session's config
    Profile: profile,

    // Provide SDK Config options, such as Region.
    Config: aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("sa-east-1"),
    },

    // Force enable Shared Config support
    SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
}
```

but that returns

> Could not initiate Kinesis client. Error: AssumeRoleTokenProviderNotSetError: assume role with MFA enabled, but AssumeRoleTokenProvider session option not set